# Unable to understand the error generated

Tags: python, indexing, range

error section-->    student_grade_system = StudentGradeSystem(sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpXYd.jpg))

errored place-->
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daphnie\Desktop\Python_code\12\student_grade\grade_system.py", line 111, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Daphnie\Desktop\Python_code\12\student_grade\grade_system.py", line 105, in main
    student_grade_system = StudentGradeSystem(sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpXYd.jpg))
IndexError: list index out of range
**Code:**

```
import sys
from student import Student
class StudentGradeSystem(object):
def __init__(self, score_file):
    self._score_file = score_file
    self._students = []
    self._class_avg = 0.0
    self._kor_avg = 0.0
    self._eng_avg = 0.0
    self._math_avg = 0.0
    self._register_students()

def _register_students(self):
    with open(self._score_file, "rt") as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            items = (line.strip()).split(",")
            num = items[0]
            name = items[1]
            kor = int(items[2])
            eng = int(items[3])
            math = int(items[4])
            student = Student(num, name, kor, eng, math)
            self._students.append(student)

def _calculate_student_order(self):
    temp_students = sorted(self._students, key = lambda x: x.total, reverse = True)
    order = 1
    for student in temp_students:
        student.order = order
        order = order + 1
    self._students = temp_students

def _calculate_class_avg(self):
    total = 0
    for student in self._students:
        total = total + student.total
    self._class_avg = total / len(self._students)

def _calculate_kor_avg(self):
    total = 0
    for student in self._students:
        total = total + student.kor
    self._kor_avg = total / len(self._students)

def _calculate_eng_avg(self):
    total = 0
    for student in self._students:
        total = total + student.eng
    self._eng_avg = total / len(self._students)

def _calculate_math_avg(self):
    total = 0
    for student in self._students:
        total = total + student.math
    self._math_avg = total / len(self._students)

def _calculate_class_information(self):
    self._calculate_class_avg()
    self._calculate_kor_avg()
    self._calculate_eng_avg()
    self._calculate_math_avg()

def process(self):
    self._calculate_student_order()
    self._calculate_class_information()

def output_result(self, output_file):
    student_output_format = "번호: {:2}, 이름: {}, 국어: {}, 영어: {}, 수학: {}, 총점: {}, 평균: {:.2f}, 등수: {}\n"

    with open(output_file, "wt") as fp:
        for student in self._students:
            student_output = student_output_format.format(student.num, student.name, student.kor, student.eng,
                    student.math, student.total, student.avg, student.order)
            fp.write(student_output)

        fp.write("\n")
        fp.write("반 평균: %.2f\n" % self._class_avg)
        fp.write("국어 평균: %.2f\n" % self._kor_avg)
        fp.write("영어 평균: %.2f\n" % self._eng_avg)
        fp.write("수학 평균: %.2f\n" % self._math_avg)
    print("성적 처리가 끝났습니다.")


def main():
student_grade_system = StudentGradeSystem(sys.argv[1])
student_grade_system.process()
student_grade_system.output_result(sys.argv[2])
if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
input("end")
```

Comment: "*shows an `IndexError`*". Please indicate the actual line in the code where the error appears, preferably with a full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What don't you understand exactly ? The error message is quite clear: you have an `IndexError` (you're trying to access a non-existant item in a list, tuple or other similar indexed sequence) at line 105, which is

```
student_grade_system = StudentGradeSystem(sys.argv[1])
```

In this line there's only one indexed access - `sys.argv[1]` - so it's obviously the culprit. Since your program obviously expects some arguments to be passed, it's your responsability to make sure 1. they are documented and 2. there are effectively passed to the program (which is obviously not the case here).